# Converting .NET Enum to GraphQL EnumerationGraphType

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, graphql-dotnet

How do I convert an enum to the EnumerationGraphType that GraphQL uses?
Here is an example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
public enum MeetingStatusType
{
    Tentative,
    Unconfirmed,
    Confirmed,
}
```

```
public class MeetingDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MeetingStatusType Status { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class MeetingStatusEnumType : EnumerationGraphType<MeetingStatusType>
{
    public MeetingStatusEnumType()
    {
        Name = "MeetingStatusType";
    }
}
```

```
public class MeetingType : ObjectGraphType<MeetingDto>
{
    public MeetingType()
    {
        Field(m => m.Id);
        Field(m => m.Name, nullable: true);
        Field<MeetingStatusEnumType>(m => m.Status); // Fails here
     }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because there's no implicit conversion from `MeetingStatusType` to `MeetingStatusEnumType`. [In the documentation](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/schema-types), the models that they were mapping would rely directly on `MeetingStatusEnumType`, but it doesn't seem good to introduce the dependency on GraphQL on something like your domain types and objects. 
I feel like I'm missing a painfully easy way to register this field, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the defination of `Field<T>` or the exact error message? I can only find one with first parameter is string.

Comment: Two errors show up: 
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'MeetingStatusType' to 'MeetingStatusEnumType'` 


`Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type` 


This is the definition of the Field overload I'm using: 

`public FieldType Field<TGraphType>(string name, 
  string description = null, 
  QueryArguments arguments = null, 
  Func<ResolveFieldContext<TSourceType>, object> resolve = null, 
  string deprecationReason = null) where TGraphType : IGraphType;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I should not have been trying to use the expression overload for mapping the fields. Switching it out to be the following instead seems to have solved the issue:

```
Field(e => e.Id);
Field(e => e.Name, nullable: true);
Field<MeetingStatusEnumType>("meetingStatus", resolve: e => e.Source.Status);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell graphql dotnet how to map the `Enum` type to the `EnumerationGraphType`.

```
GraphTypeTypeRegistry.Register(typeof(MeetingStatusType), typeof(EnumerationGraphType<MeetingStatusType>));
```

Comment: Is this a typo? I don't see anything like `GraphTypeTypeRegistry`

Comment: Here it is, not a typo... [GraphTypeTypeRegistry](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/09effc2e44d5d99edeb7bd85caa99f25c53b06d0/src/GraphQL/Utilities/GraphTypeTypeRegistry.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Another way;

```
Field(m => m.Status, type: typeof(EnumerationGraphType<MeetingStatusType>));
```